# Trying to reference foreign key field...Why is it also displaying the name of the referenced table?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display data from my template. The issue I'm having is with the foreign key in the `BattingStats` table that references `playerid` of the `PlayerInfo` table. When I get it to display, the data for that field is showing but it is wrapped in parenthesis and preceded by `ReferencedTable object`. So for me it looks like this `PlayerInfo object (smithjo05)`. Why would it be doing that and how would i get it to just show the `playerid`? Help is appreicated. Thanks.

VIEWS

```
def battingview(request):
    playerinfo = PlayerInfo.objects.all()
    playerstats = BattingStats.objects.filter(year=2018)
    return render(request, 'playerstats/battingRegStnrd2018.html', {'playerinfo':playerinfo,'playerstats': playerstats})
```

MODELS

```
class BattingStats(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    playerid = models.ForeignKey('PlayerInfo', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='playerID', blank=True, null=True)
    player = models.CharField(db_column='Player', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    hr = models.IntegerField(db_column='HR', blank=True, null=True)
    rbi = models.IntegerField(db_column='RBI', blank=True, null=True)
    ba = models.FloatField(db_column='BA', blank=True, null=True)

class PlayerInfo(models.Model):
    playerid = models.CharField(db_column='playerID', primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    namefirst = models.CharField(db_column='nameFirst', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    namelast = models.CharField(db_column='nameLast', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    debut = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    finalgame = models.CharField(db_column='finalGame', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

HTML

```
            {% for index in playerstats %}
                <td>{{ index.playerid }}</td>
                <td>{{ index.year}}</td>
                <td>{{ index.age}}</td>
                <td>{{ index.team}}</td>
                <td>{{ index.league}}</td>
            {% endfor %}

{% for index in playerstats %}
    {{ index.playerid }}
{% endfor %}
```

Browser

```
PlayerInfo object (smithjo05) 
PlayerInfo object (cruzne02)  
PlayerInfo object (jonesad01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#str) method to your `PlayerInfo` model:

```
class PlayerInfo(models.Model):
    playerid = models.CharField(db_column='playerID', primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    namefirst = models.CharField(db_column='nameFirst', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    namelast = models.CharField(db_column='nameLast', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    debut = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    finalgame = models.CharField(db_column='finalGame', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.playerid
```

This allows to change default representation of instance when you convert it to string, for example in templates.